# Create dropdown with div and select2

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create in my table a column with the possibility of assigning the task in the same way as in this image:

[image]

Can you help do something like that?

What I've been doing:

```js
var linha = ``; 

linha += `<tr id="5">
             <td class="text-center text-muted" style="vertical-align: middle;"><div class="tooltip-demo"><div class="most dropdown"><div class="caption"> <i class="pe-2x pe-va pe-7s-user"></i></div><div class="list">
      <input class="select2-search form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="search..."/>
      <div class="item">Option 1</div>
      <div class="item">Option 2</div>
    </div></div><div class="tooltip">Atribuir Membro</div></div></td>
          </tr>`;
          
$("#daberto tbody").html(linha);

$(function() {
  
  $('.dropdown > .caption').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
  });
  
  $('.dropdown > .list > .item').on('click', function() {
    $('.dropdown > .list > .item').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected').parent().parent().removeClass('open').children('.caption').text( $(this).text() );
  });
  
  $(document).on('keyup', function(evt) {
    if ( (evt.keyCode || evt.which) === 27 ) {
      $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
    }
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', function(evt) {
    if ( $(evt.target).closest(".dropdown > .caption").length === 0 ) {
      $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
.tooltip-demo {
    position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition-property: opacity, visibility;
    transition-duration: .1s;
    position: absolute;
    top: -.75rem;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
    background-color: #333;
    color: #eee;
    padding: .25rem .75rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 3.5px;
}

.most:hover ~ .tooltip,
.most:focus ~ .tooltip,
.most.active ~ .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

div.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

div.dropdown > div.caption {
  padding: 11px 40px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.dropdown > div.list {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

div.dropdown > div.list > div.item {
  padding: 11px 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.dropdown > div.list > div.item.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.dropdown > div.caption:hover,
div.dropdown > div.list > div.item:hover {
  color: #29a4f6;
}

div.dropdown.open > div.caption {
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

div.dropdown.open > div.list {
  display: block;
}

.select2 {
  position: relative;
}
.select2-list {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: overlay;
}
.select2-item:hover{
    background-color: #94adff31;
    cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pixeden-stroke-7-icon@1.2.3/pe-icon-7-stroke/dist/pe-icon-7-stroke.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="align-middle mb-0 table table-borderless table-striped table-hover daberto" id="daberto">
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center col-2">Destinatário</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the code I'm trying to create something like the image above. But in this code, when I click the search field the ocins window closes, it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Have you done something yet? If so please upload your code in here.

Comment: @Vishal Kalansooriya Yes I have, I will add to the question

Comment: @Vishal Kalansooriya I have already added the code I have, but it is not quite the same and the search field within the options does not work, because when clicking closes

Comment: @Vishal Kalansooriya Can you help me?

Comment: Ok sure I tried. Will that work for you?

Comment: @Vishal Kalansooriya I'm testing your answer, but it looks like you're not doing the research on the list. Can you test it?

Comment: I think you are talking about the functionality of the search box right? You can just do it by following the tutorial I have linked at the end of my answer I guess :) It isn't much complicated I think.

Comment: @Vishal Kalansooriya Okay, I'll try, had not noticed this link

Comment: Ah yes because I added it after your reply :)

Comment: @Vishal Kalansooriya Just one question, jquery is obsolete? Would it be better to implement in pure javascript?

Comment: It is just something like asking whether why we are going on foot bicycles even though there are a lot of motorcycles. It all depends on the situation you are in and the things you have learned so fa as well as the time you have left to spend for it. There are still pretty much helpful things that you can simply do with jQuery which takes a hundred lines of codes if you do it with pure JavaScript. But if you have the time and the knowledge, why don't you get rid of a framework and do it in a more efficient way. I personally don't like to use frameworks but if I have to use any, I surely will.

Comment: So I think if you want you can use it without watching at what the society is doing because you are the one who is actually going to do it. If you only know frameworks and don't have a good idea about pure JavaScript, then what should you do except doing it in a way you know it if it has a less time to develop your website. Also if you have any doubt like that framework will be down and no longer will be hosted, then you can simply get a copy of the jQuery and upload it as well to the place where you host it.

Comment: @Vishal Kalansooriya And how could i do it more efficiently? Is there a question in the stack that has an example for me to study and implement in my application?

Comment: So that's my opinion and just do what you can do with your level best cause users doesn't care about how your website was made but how your site is functioning:)

Comment: Sometimes there may be such examples cause all the things you have done in here can be written with just pure HTML, CSS and JS. But the number of lines you have to code will be huge and the time it gets to load the page will be less:) You will be surely able to find a way to do this only using pure JS and others mostly if you searched it outside of stack overflow. I mean just Google for it and there you go...

Comment: @Vishal Kalansooriya My problem is I don't know what expressions To use to look for what I intend to do. I'm googled for "dropdown select codepen" but I don't know if it's the correct term

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_dropdown.asp This will help you to make the structure of the thing that you intend to make. Now all you need is to just add the functionality to it. It is easy than you think. Just add an onclick function and change the dropdown box text to the value selected using innerHTML. There are a lot of other ways as well:) Googling for "How TO - Search/Filter Dropdown" will be enough I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code! By doing as follow, you can keep your window open even when you click n the search field but when you click outside of the `tr` which's id is 5, then it will close the window.

```js
var linha = ``; 

linha += `<tr id="5">
             <td class="text-center text-muted" style="vertical-align: middle;"><div class="tooltip-demo"><div class="most dropdown"><div class="caption"> <i class="pe-2x pe-va pe-7s-user"></i></div><div class="list">
      <input class="select2-search form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="search..."/>
      <div class="item">Option 1</div>
      <div class="item">Option 2</div>
    </div></div><div class="tooltip">Atribuir Membro</div></div></td>
          </tr>`;
          
$("#daberto tbody").html(linha);

$(function() {
  
  $('.dropdown > .caption').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
  });
  
  $('.dropdown > .list > .item').on('click', function() {
    $('.dropdown > .list > .item').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected').parent().parent().removeClass('open').children('.caption').text( $(this).text() );
  });
  
  $(document).on('keyup', function(evt) {
    if ( (evt.keyCode || evt.which) === 27 ) {
      $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
    }
  });
  
});


var ignoreClickOnMeElement = document.getElementById('5');

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var isClickInsideElement = ignoreClickOnMeElement.contains(event.target);
  if (!isClickInsideElement) {
    $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
  }
});
```

```css
.tooltip-demo {
    position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition-property: opacity, visibility;
    transition-duration: .1s;
    position: absolute;
    top: -.75rem;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
    background-color: #333;
    color: #eee;
    padding: .25rem .75rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 3.5px;
}

.most:hover ~ .tooltip,
.most:focus ~ .tooltip,
.most.active ~ .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

div.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

div.dropdown > div.caption {
  padding: 11px 40px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.dropdown > div.list {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

div.dropdown > div.list > div.item {
  padding: 11px 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.dropdown > div.list > div.item.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.dropdown > div.caption:hover,
div.dropdown > div.list > div.item:hover {
  color: #29a4f6;
}

div.dropdown.open > div.caption {
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

div.dropdown.open > div.list {
  display: block;
}

.select2 {
  position: relative;
}
.select2-list {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: overlay;
}
.select2-item:hover{
    background-color: #94adff31;
    cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pixeden-stroke-7-icon@1.2.3/pe-icon-7-stroke/dist/pe-icon-7-stroke.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="align-middle mb-0 table table-borderless table-striped table-hover daberto" id="daberto">
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center col-2">Destinatário</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you want to get the functionality of your search field, the below link will help you.

[How TO - Filter/Search List](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp)

Thanks and best regards!